# abs function is not giving right answer in c++?

Tags: c++

I am working on a complete pivoting method for Gaussian elimination. The only problem is with `abs()` function.

In code, the `abs` function is not giving right value 2nd time. It should give -38 while it is giving 4.4.

If anyone knows, please do tell me the error. Details: in the first loop `i` finds the maximum value and then divide the whole row by that value and then removes that row from all rows.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout.precision(3);


        float a[4][5]={{4,-4,-3,7,1.3},{8,-3,-8,17,6.6,},{12,-12,-16,29,-2.1},{-8,33,-25,36,10.4}},temp[5];
        float max=0;
        int c,cl,no=4;

    for(int ku=no;ku>=0;ku--)
    {
    for(int r=0;r<ku;r++)
    {
            for(int i=0;i<ku;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(abs(a[i][j])>max)
                {
                    max=a[i][j];
                    c=i;
                    cl=j;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<"****max:"<<max<<"*****"<<endl;
            for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            {
                if(r==c)
                {
                    a[r][k]=a[r][k]/max;
                }
            }
    }
        for(int r=0;r<ku;r++)
        {
            for(int p=0;p<5;p++)
            {
                if(r==c)
                {
                    temp[p]=a[r][p];
                }
                else
                {
                    a[r][p]=a[r][p]-(a[c][p]*a[r][cl]);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<ku;i++)
        {
                for(int pi=0;pi<5;pi++)
            {
                a[c][pi]=a[ku][pi];
                a[ku][pi]=temp[pi];
            }
        }

        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                cout<<" temp:"<<temp[j]<<"           ";
            }
            cout<<endl<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<ku-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                cout<<a[i][j]<<"           ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to narrow this down; 99% of the code here seems irrelevant. What specific input are you feeding to `abs`, and what exactly is the incorrect output that it's giving you? Also, `abs` should never be able to return `-31`. I'm not sure I understand that part correctly.

Comment: Seems like this might be a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). I also recommend that you use some better variable-naming scheme. Will make it easier to understand what all the different variables are for. As well as adding comments in the code to explain what it does, and you do it that way.

Comment: This doesn't look like a [mcve]

Comment: you are not going to get -38 from absolute value.  Rework your logic, also something is wired wrong if you are getting 4.4 instead of 38.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is `if(abs(a[i][j])>max)`, so it looks like you're comparing the magnitude.  On the next line, you assign `max=a[i][j]`, which will store a negative number.  The next iteration will replace this.

What you want to store is

```
max = abs(a[i][j]);
```

Comment: Alternatively, `if(abs(a[i][j])>abs(max))` if the negative value should be preserved, but I'm not sure whether that's what OP wants.